# What is the best way to desgin my api workflow?

Tags: design, microservices, software, distributed-system, engineering

I am building a bank management system using the microservices architecture. I have many microservices but I am going to talk about two. I have customer account service and transaction service.  Let's say a customer wants to perform a transaction(deposit/withdraw/transfer) should I define my api in transaction service or in customer account service and asynchronous notify the transaction service.
I have tried several approaches:

1. I tried defining my api in transaction service and then sends a get request to the customer service, performs some logic and then notify customer service asynchronously of customer changes. But this was bad approach, no locking mechanism, latency, consistency and all.
2. I performed all my logic in transaction service then notify the customer service asynchronously. Not satisfied with this also. No locking mechanism and eventual consistency.
3. Define all my logic in customer service and then sends asynchronous call to transaction service. This gives me concurrency control, consistency and all. But I think it's anti design because customer account service should not have a transaction controller.
4. I am yet to implement this but I am thinking .  I should define my api in transaction service and then generate a transaction id.  Return the transaction Id to the frontend and the frontend continues to poll the server for transaction response.  but I don't think this will scale.

So I need help. How should I go about it.  Thanks

Comment: If you down vote my post then at least tell me why.  I asking the questions means I am willing to learn

Comment: I agree, every down voter should be forced to say why they are doing it.

Comment: Sadly no one wants to help,  they just enjoy laughing at other people.

Comment: The problem with this question is that nobody can tell you what should you do. You have tried several options and you have realized that the choice boils down to a matter of tradeoffs. We can't say what pros outweigh the cons because it depends entirely on the project's needs. In other words, it's open to opinionated answers or discussions. Both off topic. We can't design this for you. You already did a good job, just happen that you dislike all the options. That's not a technical issue we can solve with software engineering

Comment: @Laiv thanks. I am going with approach 3.. Sounds cool right?

Comment: A customer service managing transactions is hard to sell. Note that real bank transactions are pure eventual consistency. Even when they are resolved immediately (between counts of the same bank or customer).

Comment: @Laiv I will read more on it. Thanks